# how to avoid 01-01-1900 in the text box after update statement in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

i am using date-picker in a textboxbut after i run the update statement, it adds 01-01-1900 in the database.  How can i avoid that and keep it only null if the date-picker is not selected.

```
asp:TextBox ID="txtDay1Date2" Width="80px" CssClass="datepicker" runat="server" Text='<%#  Eval("Day2Date", "{0: MM-dd-yyyy}")%>'
```

and code behind

```
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Day2Date", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtDay1Date2.Text;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDay1Date2.Text))
   cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Day2Date", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtDay1Date2.Text;
else
   cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Day2Date", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DBNull.Value;
```

Comment: `.Text` shouldn't be null. personally i would use `string.IsNullOrWhitespace`.

Comment: asp.net ensures that `.Text` won't be null - at worst it will be an empty string.

Comment: that returns a `bool`.

Comment: Rahul, the syntax seems wrong for both of them. thanks

Comment: i get this error: string does not contain definition of IsNullOrWhitespace

Comment: @moe:- string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace was added to .net framework 4.0 and up. Are you using a framework below 4.0?

Comment: @moe:- Updated  the answer. Please check now!